# Using Address Lookup table in jupiter

Tags: web3.js, versionedtransactions, jupiter

I using Jupiter for swapping.

Can I extend Jupiter Address Lookup table, or I should use own lookup table for my addresses ?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple lookup tables can be included in a versioned transaction. You can utilize the Address Lookup tables created by Jupiter in your own transactions. However, since each Lookup Table account has an authority, you will not be able to modify tables create by Jupiter. To include your own specific accounts, you will need to create your own lookup table.

```
    ...

    const lookupTableAccount = (
      await connection.getAddressLookupTable(lookupTableAddress)
    ).value
    
    const lookupTableAccount2 = (
      await connection.getAddressLookupTable(lookupTableAddress2)
    ).value
    
    
    const message = new TransactionMessage({
      payerKey: payer.publicKey, // The payer (i.e., the account that will pay for the transaction fees)
      recentBlockhash: blockhash, // The blockhash of the most recent block
      instructions: instructions, // The instructions to include in the transaction
    }).compileToV0Message([lookupTableAccount, lookupTableAccount2])
    
    const transaction = new VersionedTransaction(message)
```